# KeepAlive ajax poll in ASP.NET Core MVC does not extend session

Tags: c#, ajax, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a basic plain vanilla ASP.NET Core MVC application, no database, no authentication, just the plain templated project structure. I have just enabled session and provided an action `KeepAlive` in the `HomeController` and a respective ajax call in `Index.cshtml`.

I have also ensured that the poll is hitting the action `KeepAlive` by log statements. I have also ensured that in the client side as well.  But the session does not get extended. The session does not lose its variables by the configured 1 minute idle timeout, but rather in unpredictable timespans but definitely more than 1 minute.

Here is a sample which I captured:

Log 1: showing session start at 17:45:22 and loosing session variable after 17:53:49 i.e. 8+ minutes

```
929d12fd-2bee-0f44-ff9e-25365bb3d5a5 -> 17:45:22 => 17:53:49
```

Log 2: showing session start at 17:57:36 and loosing session variable after 18:00:49 i.e. 3+ minutes

```
d4faccb5-6be7-8521-6aea-2bdb969c2379 -> 17:57:36 => 18:00:49
```

I have gone through several threads in SO and other blogs where people were trying to suppress Ajax calls extending session duration. But I could not make this work. Please review and let me know if I am missing any.

`Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        builder.Services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        var app = builder.Build();
        app.UseSession();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

`HomeController.cs`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Start", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]        
    public IActionResult KeepAlive()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Current", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        var log = HttpContext.Session.Id + " -> " +  HttpContext.Session.GetString("Start") + " => " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("Current");
        Console.WriteLine(log);
        return Ok(log);
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@using WebApplication1.Controllers

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
<script>
    var intervalTimer = setInterval(function () {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
        var url = '@Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.KeepAlive), nameof(HomeController).Replace("Controller",""))?r='+rand;
        $.get(url);
        console.log(url);
    }, 10 * 1000);
</script>
```

Built on Microsoft.AspNetCore.App version 6.0.20

Comment: "The app uses the IdleTimeout property to determine how long a session can be idle before its contents in the server's cache are abandoned. This property is independent of the cookie expiration. Each request that passes through the Session Middleware resets the timeout." Have a look at [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Besides, call UseSession after UseRouting and before MapRazorPages and MapDefaultControllerRoute.  Why you are loosing session variable after i.e. 3+ minutes and 8+ minutes ?